# CardView Android

Tags: android, listview

Estou participando da criação de um projeto, e preciso criar uma lista contendo vários `CardViews`, como o número de `cards` não é exato, não posso fazer apenas no `XML`.

Alguém tem uma dica de qual caminho seguir pra fazer direto no `java`?
Quando o `card` for clicado ele irá abrir uma outra `activity`.

Comment: Bem vinda ao SOpt. O que você já tentou? Aproveite e leia [ask] e [tour] para conhecer como funciona o site.

Comment: Bem-vinda ao Stack Overflow, sugiro que leia: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask  e  http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  para ter mais chance de ter respostar á sua pergunta. Sobre a pergunta em si, poderia colocar a parte do código referida para podermos ajudar? O conteúdo desses card estão sendo pegos de onde?

Comment: Veja os links: http://goo.gl/JzYAFf e http://goo.gl/M0iZI1 ambos mostram como criar elementos de `listview` dinamicamente.

Comment: Tente usar um for, ai vc gera as cardviews e gera um id com o numero respectivo dela...

Answer (score 3):

Crie um activity que tenha um recyclerView:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/myRecycler"
      android:scrollbars="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
       />
</LinearLayout>
```

No onCreate da sua activity coloque:

```
        RecyclerView myRecycler = findViewById(R.id.myRecycler);
        rvDisciplina.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        SeuAdapter seuAdapter = new SeuAdapter(this,mList);
        myRecycler.setAdapter(adapterInfo);
```

Crie um adapter para controlar as views:

```
public class SeuAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SeuAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<Aluno> mList;
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private Context mContext;


public SeuAdapter(Context c, List<Aluno> l){
    mContext = c;
    mList = l;
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, viewGroup, false);
    MyViewHolder mvh =  new MyViewHolder(view);
    return mvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int position) {
    myViewHolder.txtNome.setText(mList.get(position).getNome);
    myViewHolder.txtSobrenome.setText(mList.get(position).getSobrenome);
    myViewHolder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mContext.startActivity(mContext,seuClasse.class);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mList.size();
}

public void addlisItem(Aluno a,int position){
    mList.add(a);
    notifyItemInserted(position);

}
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView txtNome;
    public TextView txtSobrenome;
    public View view;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtNome = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtNome);
        txtSobrenome = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtSobrenome);
        view = itemView;
    }
}
```

}

Crie um xml para os seus itens. Exemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_right"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_left_right"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_bottom"

    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
    app:cardMaxElevation="4dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNomeT"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorSecond"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:text="Nome"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSobrenome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:text="Nome"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Não esqueça dos compiles.

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
```

Se não ficou bem claro pra você, recomendo essa video aula [recyclerView](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMX7zRD3dhg&list=PLBA57K2L2RIKq7_IpaZRTL96CyLNDzF2F&index=2)

Comment: Bom dia amigo, porque existe esse método `addlisItem` se no adapter já passa essa lista `mList`?

Comment: Caso queira adicionar mais item a lista. Por exemplo: Já tem os itens 1 e 2 nessa lista e queira adicionar o item 3.

Comment: Consegui alterar,porém não passando a model pelo construtor, porque no meu saco meus dados vem de uma Api, aí adicionei um List da model, e depois addAll mas usando o `synchronized`

Comment: Quando você tiver os dados é so chamar     SeuAdapter seuAdapter = new SeuAdapter(this,mList);
        myRecycler.setAdapter(adapterInfo);